# DropBox cannot find correct pkg_resources.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have been using the DropBox API without any problems.  But I recently installed the Google Cloud SDK to use Google App Engine.  Now the previous code fails because (I believe) DropBox is looking for pkg_resources.py and it is mistakenly finding the similarly named file for the Google App Engine.

Here's the relevant bits from the trace:

```
File "/anaconda/envs/[REDACTED ENV NAME]/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dropbox/session.py", line 2, in <module>
import pkg_resources
File "/Users/[REDACTED HOME DIRECTORY]/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/setuptools-0.6c11/pkg_resources.py", line 29
def _bypass_ensure_directory(name, mode=0777):
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

How do I fix this?